# can't merge my branch to master

Tags: git, merge, branch

I cloned a repositroy to work in localhost and to push my work in master. i user git commit and git pull and git push and i connect to ssh to make git pull to get current version but nothing is push to server .
this my git configuration :

```
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = false
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
symlinks = false
ignorecase = true
[remote "origin"]
url = ssh://ubid_electricity@thomas-mifflin.dreamhostelectricity.com.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "frontoffice"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/frontoffice
[branch "developpement_khaled"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/developpement_khaled
[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Please provide the exact Git commands used, so that we can reproduce the situation.

Comment: git add -A    git commit -a -m "my message" git pull origin master git push origin master

Comment: Do you get some error? nothing to push? any response?

Comment: Problem resolved using : git remote set-url